# How to install old version of python by removing new version in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I want to uninstall Python 2.6.5 and then install Python 2.5. I also want to uninstall nosetests new version and install the old one.

OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Uninstall with `aptitude remove` and install with `aptitude install`?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/36443/how-can-i-downgrade-python-or-use-many-versions

Comment: Downgrading python can actually interfere with Ubuntu. This should really be asked on askubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

While this would be best asked on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) I have used the answer outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17841/will-python2-7-be-available-for-lucid-in-future/26002#26002) before. The main idea is that you can use the `Deadsnakes PPA` in combination with `virtualenv` to use the specific Python version that you need. I use it all the time to build specific package versions of `Mercurial` to deploy to my remote Linux server and it works perfectly!

You should **NOT** uninstall or downgrade the default Python on an Ubuntu machine since internal programs and services do rely on it. You will get unexpected results if you do.